# Very small font size in Windows .msi installers

Tags: windows-10, fonts, windows-installer, installer

Every .msi installer I've tried to install with has a minuscule font size I can't figure out how to fix (around 4 pixels tall). Any known way to bring it back to sensible size?

Example of an installer with a tiny font:
[image: Example of an installer with a tiny font.]

Comment: Do you have any custom display scaling or similar settings in effect?

Comment: I do not have any custom display scaling, it's at the default 100% at the moment.

Comment: Do you have an ultra HD screen?

Comment: No, just a normal 1920x1080 screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out how to fix this! The issue arises from Windows's default fonts. At some point, I downloaded a bunch of fonts that overwrote Windows defaults with bitmap versions.

Downloading a Windows 10 default font pack and replacing the ones in your Font folder should fix the issue.

Answer (score -1):

try updating your version of windows or changing the size of text, apps and other items in Settings/System/Display.
Or you can use the magnifying glass for a temporary fix

Comment: My Windows is the latest version. I've tried scaling the display a few times and restarting, with no avail. The magnifying glass would be useless in this case, as the text itself is 4 pixels tall, [this is what it looks like](https://i.imgur.com/iXNcNGs.png). However, thank you for your response.